# Check internet connection wont work

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am using Windows 10. I dont know if the OS affects the code but, on my form there is a label, and a timer. In the timer, the code is:

```
If System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable = True Then
    LabelTest.Text = "You are connected to the internet!" 
Else
    LabelTest.Text = "You are offline"`
End If
```

So, this timer is supposed to check if you are connected to the internet, but when I tried out the code, it seems not to work. I have tried pull out the Ethernet Cable, and even turn off my Router. The label still says: You are connected to internet, yes, the timer activates as soon as the form opens. I would like to know how to fix this. Thank-you!

Comment: Instead of using a timer you could use the application events that are part of the framework. But either way, this will NOT tell you if you are connected to the INTERNET. To do that, you might want to PING a few different, unrelated web sites like google and Microsoft.

Comment: Have you tried to disable your network adapter?

Comment: Yes I did that to, it didn't work.